# Get input text field from HTML into JavaScript and go to URL

Tags: javascript, html, text, input, field

How get input text field from HTML into JavaScript and go to URL?

I'm building one WebPage where you type some word into the input field and the Java gets this string and check if this string is equal to another, if it is go to some URL.

My code is:

```
 <input type="text" name="procura" id="procura" />
  <script>
  name = oForm.elements["name"].value;

  if (name.equals("Advogados"))
 {
     window.location = "http://jornalexemplo.com.br/lista%20online/advogados.html"
     //do something
 };
  </script>
```

Can you give me some lights?

Comment: I'm guessing this is javascript, not java

Comment: 1) 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I've used the **jquery** library here in my example as it makes setting up the listeners to handle these events easier.

You're referencing `oForm` in your code, but I don't see that in your examples... so I would think that you will find this easier if you wrap the  in a form tag, with a particular id (`procura`)

```
<div>
    <form method="get" id="procura">
        <input type="text" name="procura" id="procura_texto"  placeholder="Procurar"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then capture the result using the id of the input element (`procura_texto`), and jquery's `val()` method and prevent the form from being submitted using the method `preventDefault()`:

```
$("#procura").on("submit", function(event){     

    // prevent form from being submitted
    event.preventDefault();

    // get value of text box using .val()
    name = $("#procura_texto").val();

    // compare lower case, as you don't know what they will enter into the field
    if (name.toLowerCase() == "advogados")
    {
        // redirect the user.. 
        window.location.href = "http://jornalexemplo.com.br/lista%20online/advogados.html";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no redirect..(entered: " + name + ")");
    }
});
```

here's a jsfiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/zwbRa/5/

Comment: it´s almost there. the problem is when i try to fit the code in my web page it just like do some refresh..

Comment: sounds like you're not including the jquery library in the head of your page.. check out this page: http://jquery.com/download/  either download the library and install it locally, or use one of their CDNs!

Answer (score 1):

Use window.location.href = "your url".