# i want get string from Input text field and compare to some string, if it�s true send to some url

Tags: javascript, url, equals, getelementbyid, onsubmit

i still have problem in my code. i want the Java get the string froom the input text field and compare to another string, it´s true, send to some url. i did this code, but it doesn´t work.

```
<input type="text" name="procura" id="pro" value="" />


 <script language="JavaScript">
 function ver(){
    var pp = document.getElementById('pro').value;
  if (pp.equals('advogados'))
 {
     window.location = "http://www.jornalexemplo.com.br"
     //do something
 };
 };


  </script>

  </div></td>
                    <td width="399"><input type="submit" name="Busca" id="Busca"    value="AWR Procura" onsubmit="ver()"; /></td>
```

Comment: Ohhh...complete mess.Java !=javascript.

Comment: @user2497695, you asked a question similar to this 3 hours ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172367/get-input-text-field-from-html-into-javascript-and-go-to-url).  What have you learned?

Comment: Google "javascript if statement"

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `button` instead of `submit`. call that method `onClick`.

```
<input type="button" name="Busca" id="Busca"    value="AWR Procura" onClick="ver()"; />
```

**submit** only use when you need to send data on server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pp.equals`,use

```
if(pp == 'advogados')
```

then it works properly.
and change the submit button to button and call the function