# Send a user to a certain URL depending on his text field input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want the ff. done:

User inputs a text in my text field. If his text matches a text in my "list," he is sent to a certain URL once he hits the submit button.

I found a similar code on this site but his is just one specific text value. [ [Get input text field from HTML into JavaScript and go to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172367/get-input-text-field-from-html-into-javascript-and-go-to-url) ]

I want mine to determine the user's text input from a list I provide. My list will have a lot of texts/urls and it will continue to grow, so manually inputting values into the script won't work for me.. I want to be able to edit the list (possibly in an admin panel or something?) instead of the js code.

Example:

- input text: aaaa, go to URL1
- input text: mmne, go to URL2
- input text: lhfj, go to URL3
- input text: tigf, go to URL4
- input text: gred, go to URL5

Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you

```
var Something =$("#TextBoxID").val();

if(Something == "aaaa")
{
window.location.href = 'URL1'; //Will take you to URL1
} 
......
......
```

Comment: Yes but I dont want to put the input texts manually into the code. I want the code to just get everything from a list I provide

Answer (score 1):

if you want to configure the list on an admin console you need to have some kind of server side technology like php (or node.js if you want to keep using javascript). You need to think of where this data will be stored. A possibility would be fetching the list of text/url pairs using ajax (e.g. with jQuery) and storing the data in some database or in your case also a plain text file probably would suffice. The functionality you are looking for is not possible with plain HTML and JavaScript on cient side.

Comment: AJAX is an overkill for this matter. In most cases, the URLs are rarely changed during runtime, and loading them using a PHP or an ASP tag will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this, if you store your URLs on the client side (HTML/JS page):

```
function determineAndGoToURL(text) {
    var url = "#";
    switch(text) {
    case "aaaa":
        url="www.google.com";
        break;
    case "bbbb":
        url = "www.bing.com";
        break;
    default:
        url = "www.yahoo.com";
        break;
    }

    window.location.href = "http://" + url;
}
```

If you have an updated list of URLs on the server side, get them from server-side to client side, and iterate over them with a `for` statement.

I'd suggest, you'd get them from the server as JSON, and use `JSON.parse(text)` to create an object out of them, and then iterate.